# Do .. While Loop/Textfile/Operation Problem

Tags: arraylist, text-files, fseek, do-while

Hi I have a problem with the following code:

```
 int skp = 1;
    do{
    file.seekp(skp);
    file>>s;
    cout<<s;
    stats[s]++;
    skp++;
    skp++;
    }while(skp <= 10);
```

The Textfile has the following:
0

1

2

3

0

1

0

1

0

What I want this programming to do is start from reading the second number which it does, then skip one read next, skip one read the next etc. etc. what it's doing is read the second number which is good, then reads it again for 2 times, then read the next number for 3 times and the next for 3 times. So the output i receive from the above textfile is
1112223330.

Can any one help me please!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your lines are separated by line feeds (actually CR and LF). Also, `file >> s` will skip leading white space, so you end up with

```
 <CR><LF>1 
 <LF>1
 1
```

All of which result in `s` being 1.

The same is repeated for 2, 3 and so on.

Forget yout seekp() and simply use

```
while (file.good()) {
 file >> s; // skip line
 if (!file.good()) break;
 file >> s;
 cout << s;
 stats[s]++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you also solved a problem which would have emerged a few moments later with the end of file.

Comment: Ok - you may want to insert the eof() test also after the first `file >> s`. Also, instead of file.eof(), test for the more generic file.good(). --- I'll update my answer.